# Is there any provision in Google play to upload apk builds for different architecture

Tags: android

Is there any provision in Google Play to upload apk builds for different architecture like (armv-7, armv-8, x86, mips)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this two may help you:

http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/tips

Answer (score 1):

We can upload multiple apks. Google Play Developer Console provides two modes for managing the APKs associated with your application: simple mode and advanced mode. Simple mode is for apps with single apk. Advanced mode allows you to activate and publish multiple APKs. You can switch between these by clicking the link at the top-right corner of the APK files tab.

Usually, this feature is used for applications that includes native libraries built with the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html). Inorder to filter based on architecture, you have to specify it in your `Application.mk` file. Like this,

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a mips //specify the architectures you want to support
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
```

Read more about having multiple apks in Android store [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html)